# Reverse process of this code?

Tags: c

This is a signature code that I decoded:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int i;
double q[]={6627601.1454013166};
int main()
{
    if(1000.0-i++)
    {
        main();
    }
    else
    {
        puts(q);
    }
}
```

Since I am beginner in C could you please explain what is exactly happening in the code[besides recursion]?

Now, I want to know that if I want to create a similar program to print my name, what is the procedure to generate the numbers?
I tried the following:
CODE1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double a;
    scanf("%s",&a);
    printf("%lf\n",a);
}
```

CODE2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int i;
double q[]={31711421078673377979858439824814601270188287470225555299667257024608266243979287542515985597401536215834733576192.000000};

int main()
{
    if(1000.0-i++)
    {
        main();
    }
    else
    {
        puts(q);
    }
}
```

1. Why Does The second code give output only for 8 characters? [If I give input upto 7 characters, it gives output as 0.000000 and for more that 8, it gives the same output as that of 8]
2. For some inputs, it generates only 13 digits and for some, it generates 119 digits! #@#@???.
3. How can I reduce this huge number for my name to just 15-20 digits?
4. How can I get the last 4 digits of your special number [as I have already got the first 13 digits]?

Comment: Your code uses floating point types as if they are a character string -- bad things are going to happen. You can't just call `3.14` a string and get "3.14" out of it. In your case of scanning a string into a double, you're asking for a core dump.

Comment: You don't want to go there....    Yet.   Seriously, this gets into lots of hairy details about variable storage, memory layout and floating point representations.  As a beginner, you are better off learning good coding practices than figuring out how to abuse the language.

Comment: For what it's worth, when you view IEEE representation of the magic number as hex, you get 0x41594844494E4153.  When you start with the LSB and take each byte as ascii, you get SANIDHYA.  The 8 character limit is due to the fact that a double is 8 bytes.  I think the recursion on main is misdirection.  The fact that the recursion ends before a stack overflow and that there are not extra characters after the name are specific implementation details of the compiler, and likely to fail on an arbitrary system.

Comment: @AShelly - Is there a nul in that hex dump too, or is he just counting on there being one on the stack somewhere nearby to stop `puts()` before it segfaults?

Comment: @T.E.D. - `q` won't be on the stack, it will be in the global variables area.  Globals are initialized to 0 by default - (which explains why the recursion stops after 1000 levels) - There is no guarantee, but probably a reasonably good chance that there is a 0 immediately after the array, especially in a debug build.

Answer (score 1):

OK. He's taking a literal `float` adding an unintialized `int` to it, and then checking the result against integer 0. There are at least three things wrong there. Then he's telling `puts()` that a pointer to a double is actually a string he wants printed. Oh, and he's recursing on frigging **main()**!?

This horrendous mess may happen to end up doing what he wants, but in a way nobody can easily understand (and thus maintain). This is just completely unaccptable craftmanship, outside of a submission to the [International Obfuscated C Coding Contest](http://www.ioccc.org/).

So you want to know what's happening here? What's happening is that somewhere a village is missing its idiot. If you ever find the guy who wrote this, take away his compiler, by force if nessecary.

I suggest a career for him as rodeo clown. He might not be competent at that either, but in that case at least the bulls will take care of the problem.

Comment: That was a bit mean. I know this code is bad but you don't need to insult the guy. He states very clearly that he is new to this and possibly to programming as a whole. Lets be more civil.

Comment: @LamdaComplex - Read the Q again. **This is someone else's code that he's trying to decipher**. And frankly, "mean" would be allowing whoever it was that wrote that original code to remain on the loose inflicting more of it on poor maintanence software people. They have kids and families to go home to too, and stuff like this never breaks at a convienent time.

Comment: @T.E.D. - Completely agree for production code. Perhaps a bit harsh for what was probably an intentional effort by the original author to create [an obfuscated signature generator](http://www.iwriteiam.nl/SigProgC.html). I'd be happy to hire someone who understands exactly why it works, provided they promise to only use that knowledge for good.

Comment: @all: As far as I think, this code has nothing to do with stack overflow.                             The original code being: _;double __[]={6627601.1454013166};                                   
main(){1000.00-_++?main():puts(__);}

Comment: @all: So the recursion was only for balancing the lines of code. I got the signature here: http://mailman.isi.edu/pipermail/ns-developers/2010-March/007628.html . Thank you AShelly for the answer I expected.